# why socket connected twice in nodejs server with nextjs as the front end?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, next.js

I hope to get some answers here as i have been trying to debug for few days now.

The expected behaviour:
socket in server connected once when user is in my website.

The actual behaviour:
socket in server connected twice when user is in my website.

I am using Next.js as the front end and node server as backend.

_app.js

```js
  const MyApp = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
        socket.once('connect', () => {
          console.log('Connected');
        });
    
        return () => {
          socket.disconnect();
        };
      }, []);}
```

server.js

```js
let connections = [];

module.exports = function (io) {
  io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
    
    console.log(socket.id + ' connected', '\n');})}
```

Answer (score -1):

after hours of research, i finally found the answer!
[How To Implement React hook Socketio in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323350/how-to-implement-react-hook-socketio-in-next-js)
I followed the top answer and it worked! because nextjs render once in its server and its client.